# while loop + if conditional statements in an age asking program

Tags: python

I had to write a program that asks the user his age for giving him a ticket price.
Every time the user inserts a literal value I get this error: 
`age = int(input(message))`

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

and I would like the program to tell the user to insert a numerical value and then ask again, can someone help me, please?

ps. this is an exercise and it has to be written using a combination of while loops with conditional statements:

```py
    message = "Welcome to the cinema,"
    message += "\nplease enter you age: "

    age = int(input(message))
    while age:
        if age < 3:
            print(f"ok, for {age} years old people the ticket is free")
            break
        elif age in range(3, 13):
            print(f"The ticket for {age} years old people is $10")
            break
        elif age > 12:
            print(f"The ticket for {age} is $10")
            break
        else:
            print("Please, enter a valid number!")
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put input into while loop and when `ValueError` is raised, print the notification that user should enter a number.

```
age = None
while age is None: 
     try: 
         age = int(input(message)) 
     except ValueError: 
         print("Please insert number")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try/except`:

```py
message = "Welcome to the cinema,"
message += "\nplease enter you age: "


while True:

    try:
        age = int(input(message))
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
        continue

    if age < 3:
        print(f"ok, for {age} years old people the ticket is free")
        break
    elif age in range(3, 13):
        print(f"The ticket for {age} years old people is $10")
        break
    elif age > 12:
        print(f"The ticket for {age} is $10")
        break
    else:
        print("Please, enter a valid number!")
        break
```

You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)